# Get page id of any Facebook page

Tags: html, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I need to get the id of a Facebook page. I've found an online tool: https://findmyfbid.com/ - but I need it to work programmatically and I have no idea how that tool works behind the curtains.

I have noticed that Facebook exposes the id in the page source in numerous places, especially inline JS. The best thing I have found are meta tags:

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="fb://page/11239244970?referrer=app_link" />
```

That's from StackOverflow FB page. This would be good for now, but it seems very hacky and I have no idea how long will it persist.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: _Why_ do you need the IDs of arbitrary Facebook pages? If you have the page name, you can simply use that to make an API request, and get the ID back - but you would need to submit your app for the Page Public Content Access feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the following graph API endpoint:

`/officialstackoverflow/?fields=id`

You would need an app(and its access token) with the feature `Page Public Content Access` though.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS